# Internal and external division of line segment

Tags: geometry

Is there any point such that it divides a line segment both externally as well as internally in a ratio m:n (for $m \neq n$)
I tried equating the points in the formula of internal and external division but got $x_2=x_1$ and $y_2=y_1$. So does this mean no such point exist?

Comment: If a point divides AB internally, then it lies on the segment AB.
And if a point divides AB externally, then it lies on the line AB outside the segment AB.
So there is no point which divides a segment both internally and externally.

Comment: If you are seeking points that are either internally or externally, than there are four such points that are derived from a quadratic equation.